# BCM Bladelogic Conditional statements in NSH

Tags: shell

I am having trouble writing a simple if statement in a BMC Bladelogic NSH shell script.

My question is what is the proper syntax to write a statement that compares two strings to see if they are equal or not.  I understand how an if statement works the problem seems to be syntax.

An example of what I have tried is as follows where **$PLATFORM** is a string represintation of the server such as "*aix*" and **$AIX** is "*aix*"

```
if [ $PLATFORM == $AIX ];then 
 #do stuff
else
 #do other stuff
fi
```

This is a very specific question for if you deal with BMC Bladelogic NSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I feel foolish the answer is actually as such:

```
if [ $PLATFORM = $AIX ];then  
 #do stuff 
else 
 #do other stuff 
fi
```

I knew it would be something very simple.